# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable. This is the worst error that I been trying to remove help me please

Tags: python, tkinter

So I been trying to remove this error but I want this single code

```
if "hi" in command:
    talk("Hello, master")
```

the error shows like this

```
if "test" in command:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

is there any way that I can remove this thing and help to me make my dream come If I somehow remove this 1 error I can move to the next step of printing it and making the sign up, password checks, email code sending and other fuln things that it can do please help me and by the way there is the full code is you need any context

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyjokes
from pygame import mixer
import os
import datetime
import wikipedia
from tkinter import *
from functools import *

win = Tk()
win.title("app")
win.config(bg="white")
win.geometry("600x600+0+0")

Listenter = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voices', voices[1].id)


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("listening currently...")
            voice = Listenter.listen(source)
            command = Listenter.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'jarvis' in command:
                command = command.replace('jarvis', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass


command = take_command()
button = Button(win, text="test", command=command)
button.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)
if "hi" in command:
    talk("Hello, master")

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: `take_command()` doesn't return a value. You should replace `print` with `return`

Answer (score 3):

Replace `print(command)` with `return command` to return the command value so that `command = take_command()` equals the returned command value. You are getting a TypeError (None) because the function does not return a value thus essentially assigning nothing to the command variable when you equal it to the function.

Have also changed the `command = take_command()` to `command_ = take_command()`

```
def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("listening currently...")
            voice = Listenter.listen(source)
            command = Listenter.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'jarvis' in command:
                command = command.replace('jarvis', '')
                return command
    except:
        pass


command_ = take_command()
button = Button(win, text="test", command=command_)
button.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)
if "hi" in command_:
    talk("Hello, master")
```

Comment: dude I did what you said but it is not working as it shows
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment 
`line 42, in <module> command1 = take_command() line 40, in take_command return command`

Comment: @goodcoder I've updated the code and changed the outer `command` variable name to `command_`. I've tested this code on my end and it worked so it should work now

Comment: No now its showing `line 44, in <module> if "hi" in command_:  TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`

what the heck is wrong with this and I should really learn some errors